Proving the Similarity between Triangles with Vertices on Circumcenters and Incenters
I have encountered the following conjecture while solving an olympiad problem:
Given triangle $ABC$, let $O$ be its circumcenter, $I$ its incenter, $J$ its $A$-excenter, and $D$ the foot of perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. Suppose $AO$ meets the circumcircle again at $X$, and ray $AI$ meets segment $BC$ at $E$, circle $O$ at $M$. Then $\triangle AID \sim \triangle AXJ$.
I have been able to show that $M$ is the midpoint of segment $IJ$, and $\angle DAI = \angle JAX$. Thus we would only need to show that $AI\cdot AJ = AE\cdot AM$. I suppose an inversion about $A$ would be helpful here, but I'm not sure how to approach it. Thank you!

FYI: I've proven the conjecture with quick-and-dirty Mathematica-assisted coordinate argument. (The scale factor for the triangles is $2\sin(B/2)\sin(C/2)$.) So, all that remains is to find a "good" proof.

@Blue could you please read the answer I've posted? I still think a simpler proof exists, but I gave all I have.

Do you know about root bc inversion? It kills this problem inmediatly.

By the way $AI\cdot AJ=AE\cdot AM$  is true in general for any harmonic division $AE,IJ$, where $M$ is the midpoint of $IJ$.

@Antonio Not before you mentioned it. Thank you for writing out the solution. It was slick!

@mathy_mathema https://www.olympiadgeometry.com/the-book.html  This book has a good chapter on inversion, with some examples on root bc inversion (chapter 20).

Synthetic solution: First notice that
$$\angle BAD=90º-\angle ABC=\angle OAC=\angle XAC$$ and
$$\angle BDA=90º=\angle XCA$$
Therefore $$\triangle ABD\sim \triangle AXC \implies \frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{AX}{AC} \implies AD\cdot AX= AB\cdot AC$$
Now reflect $C$ with respect to line $AI$. Call this reflection $C'$. Since AI is the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$, we have $C'\in AB$. Since $\angle IBJ=90º=\angle ICJ$, the points $B$, $C$, $I$, $J$ lie on a circle with diameter $IJ$, that is, symmetric with respect to ${IJ}\equiv {AI}$.
By symmetry, $C'$ also lies on this circle, so by power of a point $$AI\cdot AJ= AB\cdot AC'= AB\cdot AC$$
In conclusion$$AI\cdot AJ= AB\cdot AC=AD\cdot AX \implies\frac{AB}{AI}=\frac{AJ}{AC}$$ which along with $$\angle DAI=\angle BAI-\angle BAD=\angle JAC-\angle XAC=\angle JAX$$ implies $$\triangle ADI\sim \triangle AJX$$ as desired.


[Posting this trigo solution because it's much simplier than the other 2 solutions here.]
OP says that $\angle DAI = \angle JAX$, which follows by direct angle chasing. So it remains to show that $AI \cdot AJ = AD \cdot AX$.  Let's calculate these lengths

$AD = c \sin \beta$   (height of triangle)
$ AX = \frac{c}{ \sin \gamma } $ (diameter of circumcircle, from extended sine rule)
$AI$ - $\triangle AIB: \frac{AI}{\sin \beta/2 } = \frac{ AB} { \sin (180 - \alpha/2 - \beta / 2 } \Rightarrow AI = \frac{ c \sin \beta/2 } { \cos \gamma/2}.  $
$AJ$ - $\triangle AJB$: $\frac{AJ}{\sin (90 + \beta/2) } = \frac{ AB} { \sin (180 - 90  - \beta/2 - \alpha/2) } \Rightarrow AJ = \frac{ c\cos \beta/2}{\sin \gamma/2} $

Hence,
$$ AI \cdot AJ = \frac{ c^2 \sin \beta } { \sin \gamma } = AD \cdot AX. $$
Bonus: OP also mentioned its equivalent to showing that $AI \cdot AJ = AE \cdot AM$.

$AE$ - $\triangle AEB:$ $\frac{AE}{ \sin \beta} = \frac{ AB}{\sin (180 - \alpha/2  - \beta ) } \Rightarrow AE = \frac{c \sin \beta} { \sin (\alpha/2 + \beta) }  $
$AM$ - $\triangle AMB$: $\frac{ AM}{\sin (\beta + \alpha/2 ) } = \frac{AB}{\sin \gamma } \Rightarrow AM = \frac{ c\sin ( \beta + \alpha/2)}{\sin \gamma}  $

Hence,
$$ AI \cdot AJ =  AD \cdot AX = AE \cdot AM. $$
Note

Since $\frac{b}{\sin \beta } = \frac{c}{\sin \gamma}$, the product is also equal to $bc$ per mathy_mathema's solution.


I've successfully proven my claim using some elementary methods, but its complexity incites me to wonder about simpler solutions. Nevertheless, I present my proof here:
From now on we will refer to $BC, AC, AB$ as $a,b,c$, respectively. First, note that $\angle DAI = \angle JAX$ since $\angle BAE = \angle CAE$ and $\angle BAD = \angle XBC = \angle XAC$. We show that $\triangle DAI \sim \triangle JAX$ by S.A.S. similarity; that is, we aim to show that $AD\cdot AX = AI \cdot AJ$. Since $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle AMX$, we must have $AD\cdot AX=AE \cdot AM$. Now comes our crucial claim:
$bc=AE\cdot AM = AI \cdot AJ$.
To prove that $bc=AE\cdot AM$, note that $AE\cdot EM = BE\cdot EC$. We apply Stewart's Theorem to $AE$ and obtain that $$AE^2=\frac{c^2\cdot CE+b^2\cdot BE-a\cdot CE\cdot BE}{a}.$$ This implies $AE\cdot AM=AE^2+BE\cdot EC=\frac{c^2}{a}\cdot CE+\frac{b^2}{a}\cdot BE = b\left(\frac{c+b}{a}\right)\cdot BE$. It is fairly obvious that $BE=\frac{ac}{c+b}$, so we could conclude that $AE\cdot AM = bc$.
By my previous observations that $M$ is the midpoint of $IJ$ combined with the classic fact that both triangles $\triangle BIM$ and $\triangle IMC$ are isosceles, we could prove that $BICJ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with circumcenter $M$. $AI\cdot AJ$ would therefore be the power of point $A$ with respect to circle $M$. Therefore, by power of a point, if we let circle $M$ intersect ray $AB$ again at $T$, we would be able to conclude that $AI\cdot AJ= AB\cdot AT$. Note that $$BT= 2BM\cdot \cos{\left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)}=a\frac{\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)}{\cos\frac{A}{2}}$$ since $\triangle BMC$ is isosceles and all its angles are expressible using $\triangle ABC$'s angles. Therefore, it remains for us to show that $$AI\cdot AJ=c\cdot \left(c+a\frac{\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)}{\cos\frac{A}{2}}\right).$$
Indeed, we could argue that the following claim holds:
Given $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a,b,c$ and angles $A,B,C$, one must have \begin{equation}b=c+\frac{a\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)}{\cos\frac{A}{2}}.\end{equation}
To prove this, first note that $\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)=\sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$. We have $$\begin{equation} \frac{b-c}{a}=\frac{\sin{B}-\sin{C}}{\sin{A}}\end{equation}=\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)}{\sin{(B+C)}}$$ by the law of sines as well as the sum to product formula. Thus, $$\begin{equation}\left(\frac{b-c}{a}\right)\cos\frac{A}{2}=\left(\frac{b-c}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)\end{equation},$$
implying that our claim is true. Therefore, we could conclude that $AI\cdot AJ=AE\cdot AM=bc$, and $\triangle AID \sim \triangle AXJ$.

FYI The calculations can be greatly simplified. See my solution.
